# Run python multiprocessing with Lock()

Tags: python, multiprocessing, locking, python-multiprocessing

i have multiprocessing script with "pool.imap_unordered".

I want to use

```
multiprocessing.Lock()
```

can you write the right way of using for the following script?

```
import multiprocessing

def my_func(df):

   # modify df here
   # ...
   # df = df.head(1)
   return df

if __name__ == "__main__":
    df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6], 'c': [4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6]})
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
        groups = (g for _, g in df.groupby("a"))
        print(df)
        print(groups)
        out = []
        for res in pool.imap_unordered(my_func, groups):
            out.append(res)
    final_df = pd.concat(out)
```

Comment: Why do you want to use a lock?

Comment: it turns out that lock() does not apply to the original problem, I described it in another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77324716/stucking-of-python-multiprocessing-pool Thank you for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to use a lock to serialize updates to the `df` being passed to your worker function, `my_func`, then the code below is how you would do it.

But the question is why would you want to do that? A lock might be required if multiple processes were modifying the same element using an operation that was not atomic where that element is *sharable*. That is, it only makes sense if a change made by one process was visible to another process. But that is clearly not the case here because the passed `df` argument is not such a sharable structure.

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import pandas as pd

def init_pool(*args):
    global lock

    lock = args[0]

def my_func(df):
    # Why are we using a lock here?
    with lock:
        # Modify df here
        ...
    return df


if __name__ == "__main__":
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        {"a": [2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3], "b": [4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6], "c": [4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6]}
    )
    lock = mp.Lock()
    with mp.Pool(initializer=init_pool, initargs=(lock,)) as pool:
        groups = (g for _, g in df.groupby("a"))
        out = pool.imap_unordered(my_func, groups)
        rdf = pd.concat(out)
        print('----------\n', rdf, sep='')
```

**Example Showing a Valid Use for a Lock**

In the following example we create a *sharable* integer value initialized to 0 and submit 3 tasks where each task is incrementing the value 1000 times. The final value should be 3000. If the increment operation `v.value += 1` as not done under control of a lock, the final value may not be 3000 since the incrementing is not atomic: First the current value is fetched into some temporary, the temporary is incremented, and finally the incremented value is stored back. Only the use of a lock prevents two processes from fetching the same value and incrementing it to the same final value. Note that this `multiprocessing.Value` instance is created with its own internal lock that is obtained with the call `v.get_lock()`:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp

def init_pool(*args):
    global v

    v = args[0]

def my_func():
    for _ in range(1000):
        with v.get_lock():
            v.value += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    v = mp.Value('i', 0, lock=True)
    N_TASKS = 3
    pool = mp.Pool(min(N_TASKS, mp.cpu_count()), initializer=init_pool, initargs=(v,))
    for i in range(N_TASKS):
        pool.apply_async(my_func)
    # Wait for all tasks to complete:
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print(v.value)
```

Prints:

```None
3000
```

In the following example we create a sharable array of 3 integers. But since each task is incrementing a different element of the array, we do not require a lock:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp

def init_pool(*args):
    global arr

    arr = args[0]

def my_func(idx):
    for _ in range(1000):
        arr[idx] += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    N_TASKS = 3
    arr = mp.Array('i', [0] * N_TASKS, lock=False)
    pool = mp.Pool(min(N_TASKS, mp.cpu_count()), initializer=init_pool, initargs=(arr,))
    pool.map(my_func, range(N_TASKS))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    # Convert to a list for easy printing:
    print(list(arr))
```

Prints:

```None
[1000, 1000, 1000]
```